# Как загрузить в фон окна изображение с альфа-каналом (чтобы он работал)?

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

При задании параметров класса окна указываю:

```
WindowClass.hbrBackground = CreatePatternBrush((HBITMAP)LoadImageA(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(TEST), IMAGE_BITMAP, 320, 320, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION));
```

(при такой загрузке изображения RGBA, иконки в трей-меню получались с альфой)

После регистрации класса создаю окно:

```
CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_TOPMOST, WindowClass.lpszClassName, ApplicationTitleA.c_str(), WS_POPUP, (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - AW_WIDTH) / 2, (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - AW_HEIGHT) / 2, AW_WIDTH, AW_HEIGHT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

(без рамок, прозрачное, если `.hbrBackground` не загружать).

Изображение `TEST` из ресурсов - это 32-битный bmp-файл (RGBA).

**Как загрузить его так, чтобы поддерживалась альфа изображения?** Там, где должны просматриваться лежащие ниже окна и рабочий стол, - сейчас чёрный фон.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классическое решение: используйте `WS_EX_LAYERED` совместно с `UpdateLayeredWindow`.

---

Для примера я взял стандартную заготовку visual studio для оконного приложения.
Добавил в ресурсы первый же `png` "с альфой", который нашел:

[image]

В файл ресурсов `*.rc` для этого надо добавить строку:

```
IDI_SOTEST9             RCDATA         "penguin.bmpx"
```

`penguin.bmpx` я получил из png, пропустив его через `Paint.Net`.

Затем, в `WndProc` добавил возможность таскать окно за его клиентскую область:

```
case WM_NCHITTEST:
    return HTCAPTION;
```

И расширил код инициализации, в `InitInstance`:

```
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;
   BLENDFUNCTION blend;
   POINT ptPos, ptSrc;
   SIZE sizeWnd;
   HDC hdcScreen, hdcMem;
   HGDIOBJ hBitmap;
   HRSRC hRSrc;
   HGLOBAL hRes;
   BITMAPFILEHEADER *pRes;
   BITMAPINFOHEADER *bi;
   void *bits, *premultiply;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if( !hWnd ) {
       return FALSE;
   }

   // load resource
   hRSrc = FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SOTEST9), RT_RCDATA);
   hRes = LoadResource(hInstance, hRSrc);
   pRes = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)LockResource(hRes);
   bi = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(pRes + 1);
   bits = ((char*)pRes) + pRes->bfOffBits;

   // premultiply
   premultiply = malloc(bi->biHeight * bi->biWidth * sizeof(RGBQUAD));
   for( int c = bi->biHeight * bi->biWidth; c--; ) {
       RGBQUAD &src = ((LPRGBQUAD)bits)[c];
       RGBQUAD &dst = ((LPRGBQUAD)premultiply)[c];
       dst.rgbRed = (BYTE)MulDiv(src.rgbRed, src.rgbReserved, 255);
       dst.rgbGreen = (BYTE)MulDiv(src.rgbGreen, src.rgbReserved, 255);
       dst.rgbBlue = (BYTE)MulDiv(src.rgbBlue, src.rgbReserved, 255);
       dst.rgbReserved = src.rgbReserved;
   }

   hdcScreen = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);

   // prepare bitmap
   hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, bi->biWidth, bi->biHeight);
   hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
   hBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
   SetDIBitsToDevice(
       hdcMem, 0, 0, bi->biWidth, bi->biHeight,
       0, 0, 0, bi->biHeight, premultiply, (BITMAPINFO*)bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS
   );

   free(premultiply);

   // prepare window
   memset(&blend, 0, sizeof(blend));
   blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
   blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
   blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
   sizeWnd.cx = bi->biWidth;
   sizeWnd.cy = bi->biHeight;
   ptPos.x = 0;
   ptPos.y = 0;
   ptSrc.x = 0;
   ptSrc.y = 0;
   UpdateLayeredWindow(hWnd, hdcScreen, &ptPos, &sizeWnd, hdcMem, &ptSrc, 0, &blend, ULW_ALPHA);

   // cleanup
   ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdcScreen);
   hBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
   DeleteDC(hdcMem);
   DeleteObject(hBitmap);

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}
```

Все, фон окна теперь с альфой, и без подключения дополнительных библиотек:

[image]

Поясню некоторые нюансы:

1. У Paint.Net `bmpx` - это [тот же 32-битный bmp, только с альфой](https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/11201-alpha-32bits-bitmap-support-for-paintnet/). Можно воспользоваться `Adobe Photoshop`, он имеет тот же функционал.
2. Ресурс загружаю вручную, т.к. `LoadImage` не умеет загружать растры "с альфой". `SetDIBitsToDevice` подгружает альфу.
3. Для полноценной работы с прозрачностью, перед загрузкой растра важно выполнить [стандартный premultiply](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/PremultipliedAlpha.htm). Работать будет и без него, но неполноценно.

---

[Ссылка на упакованный проект **zip** (если не получилось разобраться)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ncau2ra6s1cf8m1/so-703157.zip?dl=0)
[Ссылка на exe (кто не боится)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvyuq3k150hww5u/so-703157.exe?dl=0)

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Ну, конечно, у вас так это работать не будет. Того и стоило, вообщем то, ожидать.

Для решения проблемы используйте функции из Desktop Windows Manager API: [`DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa969512(v=vs.85).aspx) (поддерживается начиная с Windows Vista).

Для установки стеклянного фрейма **нужно сделать следующее**:

> Use negative margin values to create the "sheet of glass" effect where the client area is rendered as a solid surface with no window border.

А потом уже лепите свою полупрозрачную картинку на фон. Думаю, это должно помочь.