# Отображение изображения, с прозрачным фоном на рабочем столе

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте, друзья! Пожалуйста, помогите решить задачу. Пишу программу, где котенок будет бегать по рабочему столу. Есть картинки кошечки, формата png/gif. Не удается вывести на рабочий стол картинку, где не будет видно фона/окна(формы), а будет видна только киса, в картинке которой прозрачный фон. Разрабатываю код средствами с++ winapi. Может кто знает как вывести изображение png/gif средствами с++ winapi, т.к. функцией LoadImage мне удается выводить только bmp и д.р. Нашел пример, где применяется библиотека GdiPlus, но с ней я не знаком, поэтому просто вставил функцию вывода картинки в программу и когда я заставляю программу выводить картинки одна за другой через функцию библиотеки GdiPlus, они накладываются друг на друга и моих знаний, для очистки изображений не хватает. InvalidateRect не помогает.
Пример функции вывода изображения, библиотекой GdiPlus приведен ниже.

```
void draw()
{//отрисовка изображения gif
    // Создаем контекст рисования и устанавливаем 
    // пиксельную систему координат

    Graphics g(hdc);

    g.SetPageUnit(UnitPixel);
    RectF bounds(0, 0, float(w), float(h));

    // Загружаем фоновое изображение и растягиваем его на все окно
    std::wstring wstr = strToWstring(animations[STATE][(int)currAnim]);
    LPWSTR lpstr = (LPWSTR)wstr.c_str();
    Image bg(lpstr);//L"b.gif"
    g.DrawImage(&bg, bounds);
    g.ResetTransform();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Совсем недавно отвечал на аналогичный вопрос: [Как загрузить в фон окна изображение с альфа-каналом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705615/8766). Вам надо просто перевести свои `png/gif` в формат `bmpx`. А как загрузить `bmpx` - подробно описано в ответе (с рабочим exe и проектом)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, друзья! Все получилось! Отдельное спасибо программисту mega, Ваш пример мне очень помог! 
Выложу пример кода, на случай, если кто столкнется с подобной задачей. Данный код выводит анимацию с прозрачным фоном на экран, последовательно перебирая изображения:

---

```
//объявим идентификаторы для картинок
файл: *.rc
IDC_KISS01   RCDATA  "cat\kiss_01.bmpx"
IDC_KISS02   RCDATA  "cat\kiss_02.bmpx"
...
IDC_KISS22   RCDATA  "cat\kiss_22.bmpx"

файл: Resource.h
#define IDC_KISS01  111
#define IDC_KISS02  112
...
#define IDC_KISS22  132

//класс, отвечающий за анимацию
class CAT{

public:

CAT(){
    STATE = "kiss";
    ptSrc.x = 0;
    ptSrc.y = 0;
}

void loadAnimations(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hInstance, std::string nameAmim, int nCount, float sp)
{//загрузим каждую картинку-объект в структуру данных для работы с изображениями
    hwndAnim = hwnd;
    speed = sp;
    HGDIOBJ hBitmap;
    HRSRC hRSrc;
    HGLOBAL hRes;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER *pRes;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER *bi;
    void *bits, *premultiply;
    std::vector<alpha> v;

    int id;
    if (nameAmim == "kiss") id = 111;
    for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++){

        // load resource
        hRSrc = FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(id++), RT_RCDATA);
        hRes = LoadResource(hInstance, hRSrc);
        pRes = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)LockResource(hRes);
        bi = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(pRes + 1);
        bits = ((char*)pRes) + pRes->bfOffBits;

        // premultiply
        premultiply = malloc(bi->biHeight * bi->biWidth * sizeof(RGBQUAD));
        for (int c = bi->biHeight * bi->biWidth; c--;) {
            RGBQUAD &src = ((LPRGBQUAD)bits)[c];
            RGBQUAD &dst = ((LPRGBQUAD)premultiply)[c];
            dst.rgbRed = (BYTE)MulDiv(src.rgbRed, src.rgbReserved, 255);
            dst.rgbGreen = (BYTE)MulDiv(src.rgbGreen, src.rgbReserved, 255);
            dst.rgbBlue = (BYTE)MulDiv(src.rgbBlue, src.rgbReserved, 255);
            dst.rgbReserved = src.rgbReserved;
        }

        a.hdcScreen = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);

        // prepare bitmap
        hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(a.hdcScreen, bi->biWidth, bi->biHeight);
        a.hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(a.hdcScreen);
        hBitmap = SelectObject(a.hdcMem, hBitmap);
        SetDIBitsToDevice(
            a.hdcMem, 0, 0, bi->biWidth, bi->biHeight,
            0, 0, 0, bi->biHeight, premultiply, (BITMAPINFO*)bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS
            );
        a.sizeWnd.cx = bi->biWidth;
        a.sizeWnd.cy = bi->biHeight;
        free(premultiply);

        // prepare window
        memset(&a.blend, 0, sizeof(a.blend));
        a.blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
        a.blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
        a.blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

        v.push_back(a);
    }//for

    //cleanup
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, a.hdcScreen);
    //hBitmap = SelectObject(a.hdcMem, hBitmap);
    DeleteDC(a.hdcMem);
    //DeleteObject(hBitmap);

    //в некоторых случаях могут быть не точные расчеты, т.к. получаем размеры последней картинки
    width  = a.sizeWnd.cx;
    heigth = a.sizeWnd.cy;

    animations.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::vector<alpha>>(nameAmim, v));
}

void playAnim()
{//проигрываем анимацию из таймера
    currAnim += 1 * speed;
    //!!! необходимо перенести в участок, где происходит смена состояния 
    int cout = animations[STATE].size();
        a = animations[STATE][(int)currAnim];
        UpdateLayeredWindow(hwndAnim, a.hdcScreen, &ptPos, &a.sizeWnd,    a.hdcMem, &ptSrc, 0, &a.blend, ULW_ALPHA);
        if ((int)currAnim >= cout - 1) currAnim = 0;            
}


void setPos(int &x, int &y)
{
    ptPos.x = x; ptPos.y = y;
}

private:
struct alpha
{//структура данных загружаемых изображение 
    BLENDFUNCTION blend;
    HDC hdcScreen, hdcMem;
    SIZE sizeWnd;
}a;

float speed, currAnim;
std::map<std::string, std::vector<alpha>> animations;
std::string STATE;//stand, kiss
HWND hwndAnim;
POINT ptPos, ptSrc;
int width, heigth;//w\h img
};
```

P.S. В данном примере используется функция loadAnimations() которая взята из примера: [Как загрузить в фон окна изображение с альфа-каналом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/703157/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB/705615#705615)

Comment: отметь, пожалуйста, свой ответ, как правильный, чтобы другим было проще ориентироваться.

Answer (score 1):

Делал так

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include <QLayout>
    #include <QLabel>
    #include <QTimer>
    #include <QtDebug>
    #include <QDesktopWidget>
    #include <QApplication>

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
        : QWidget(parent)
    {
  #------------------------------------
        setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

        setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
  #-------------------------------------
        QPixmap pix;

        QLabel* lbl = new QLabel("Test");
        QLayout* lay = new QVBoxLayout();



        pix.load("../mouse.png");
        lbl->resize(pix.size());


        lbl->setPixmap(pix);

        lay->addWidget(lbl);
        setLayout(lay);

        resize(lbl->size());

        QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
        timer->start(5);

        QRect rec = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
        p.setY((rec.height()-height())/2);
        p.setX((rec.width()-width()));
        move(p);
        qDebug() << p;

    }

    void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
    {
        if(x() <= 0) delta = 1;
        if(x() >= p.x()) delta = -1;
        move(x()+delta,y());
        QWidget::paintEvent(event);
    }

    void MainWindow::show()
    {
        QWidget::show();
        p = pos();
        qDebug() << p;
    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {

    }
```

Получилось так, изображение мыши двигается через экран по таймеру
[image: мышь]

Answer (score 0):

Изображение в формате .gif можно представить себе, как набор разных frame-ов (или много много картинок идущих друг за другом). Эти фреймы надо сменять в определенном порядке и с определенной задержкой. Поэтому обычно привязываются к **WM_TIMER** или пишут свой собственный таймер для смены фреймов.

Из приведённой части кода сложно судить о том, как именно ты работаешь с фреймами и таймером.

Предлагаю тебе посмотреть следующие две ссылки:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1776/Adding-GIF-animation-using-GDI
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27387/Play-GIF-using-GDI