# Как сделать форму из картинки (png) с полупрозрачными областями?

Tags: delphi, winapi, формы

Нужно создать полностью прозрачную форму, на которую наложить PNG картинку с полупрозрачными элементами, соответственно на этой картинке разместить элементы управления.

Проблема в том что при наложении на форму полупрозрачной PNG, все полупрозрачные элементы а так же тени - подсвечиваются (красным):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: слоистые окошки вам, наверное, в помощь

Comment: Исправьте, пожалуйста, вопрос и напишите как вы добились того, что у вас уже есть и что вы еще пробовали. Возможно, отвечающим на ваш вопрос поможет пример вашего кода. Укажите используемую версию Delphi и фреймворк (VCL или FMX).

Comment: Был такой ответ, правда на Си: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705615/8766

Comment: Вам необходимо использовать функцию [UpdateLayeredWindow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatelayeredwindow), которая позволит Вам создать окно на основе PNG-файла. Единственное ограничение: все компоненту не будут реагировать на сообщение `WM_PAINT`, в этом, собственно, заключается проблема совмещения VCL-компонентов и "слоистого" окна. Очевидный выход - отрисовка необходимых компонентов на *рисунке формы (тот самый PNG-файл)* "руками".

Answer (score 0):

Тут реализовано https://github.com/Dev-Demi/GLEngine2D/tree/master/Demos/%5BGLEngine%5DAlphaForm
Там идет рендер а БМП 32 бит, а по ней динамически строится форма.
Можно переделать под PNG без проблем.